# Problems with PHP header() and php require_once()

Tags: php, header, require-once

When I use this code alone is no problem:

```
<?php 
$url='image.jpg'; 
header('content-type: image/jpeg'); 
readfile($url); 
?>
```

But when I want to write this code is not shown in the output:

```
<?php
require_once("sql.php");
$db = new db();
$db->connect();

$sql = $db->query("select * from image where name='test.jpg'");
$row = $db->fetch_array();
$url = $row["url"];
header('content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile($url);
exit;
?>
```

The problem is when would I use header() with the require_once().
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09p6l.jpg)
In both codes Photo's sure the url address is correct.
Thank you for your help.

**and when remove header output is: **
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbrp0.jpg)

Comment: Try to be more specific and add to your question the exact error the PHP interpreter shows you.

Comment: According to [RFC2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2) the field name (e.g. `Content-Type`) is case-sensitive.

Comment: Did you check if ```$url = $row["url"];``` has expected value?

Comment: yes, $url have true value.

Answer (score 0):

oh my god, I knew where the problems are.

```
require_once("sql.php");
```

my sql.php class have problem.
i write direct code for connect to MySQL.